# Considerations to architect well designed dependencies

Tags: design-patterns, inversion-of-control, dependency-management

I'm starting to consider implementing Inversion of Control containers in my future projects or refactorings and I was wondering which principles (besides GoF patterns) might be interesting to keep in mind when it comes to properly design dependencies. Say I need to architect a simple console app that will search for a book (by ISBN) in Amazon if it can access the internet or will fallback to a local database (SQLite, SqlServerCE) when there is no connection available. So the initial design might pretty much be:

- IAmazonSearchProvider
- ILocalSearchProvider
- IResultsGenerator (depending on either IAmazonSearchProvider or ILocalSearchProvider)
- IOutputFormatter
- ConsoleApplication (depends on IOutputFormatter)

Any guidance will be really appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: as long as dependencies are linear and not cyclic you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty normal approach, and it's not bad, but it focuses much on mechanics and may entail the risk of violating the [Reused Abstractions Principle](http://www.codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934). At a high level, you'd be better off if you can make the API describe *what* it does instead of *how* it does it. Following the [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle) is an important start.

When designing abstractions, *favor composition over inheritance*. Apart from that, favor [Role Interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) over [Header Interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HeaderInterface.html).

Currently, I work with a [loose ranking of Role Interface methods](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/03/TowardsBetterAbstractions.aspx) like this (where [Commands are best](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/22/CommandsAreComposable.aspx)):

1. Commands
2. Closure of Operations
3. Reduction of Input
4. Composable Return Types

Comment: Mark, I want to thank you for this contribution, I've found it quite informative. I'll be looking forward to get a copy of your upcoming book.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `I*` are interfaces. `IResultsGenerator` and `ILocalSearchProvider` sounds like implementations (and so not interfaces) of `IResultsGenerator`. Also something should depend on `IResultsGenerator`, I recommend it's `ConsoleApplication`.

The rest looks fine.

Comment: You're probably right - I've just inspired my sample on Spring.NET's CodeConfig reference: http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/migration-example.html